# Java Servlet exception when trying to upload image in mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, servlets

This is my upload form:

```
form id='picform' action='UploadImage' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
   <input type='file' name='Photo' />
<input type='submit' />
</form>
```

and my UploadServlet:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

@WebServlet("/uploadServlet")
@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 16177215) 
public class UploadImage extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    Part filePart = request.getPart("Photo");
    if (filePart != null) {
        System.out.println(filePart.getName());
        System.out.println(filePart.getSize());
        System.out.println(filePart.getContentType());

        inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();            
    }

String message = null; 
    try{

    //loading drivers for mysql
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

      Connection  con=DriverManager.getConnection
                 ("jdbc:mysql://195.243.249.131:3306/****","****","****");

    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement
              ("update users set Photo=? where email=?");
HttpSession session=request.getSession(false);
String email=(String)session.getAttribute("email");

    ps.setString(1, email);
    int i=ps.executeUpdate();

        if (inputStream != null) {
            // fetches input stream of the upload file for the blob column
            ps.setBlob(3, inputStream);
        }

        int row = ps.executeUpdate();
        if (row > 0) {
            message = "Image is uploaded successfully into the Database";
        }        
    }
          catch(Exception se)
    {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }   
   }
  }
```

but i get this exception when trying to upload a file:

> java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getPart(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/servlet/http/Part;
>     UploadImage.doPost(UploadImage.java:21)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)

Comment: And your Tomcat version is...?

Comment: Apache Tomcat/6.0.41

Comment: And that's the problem - Tomcat 6 implements Servlet API v2.5, whereas native file upload API is available from Servlet API v3.0, i.e. Tomcat 7. See [this table](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) and the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2424824/3511123